# JAVA - Binary search - return index of key

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search

I have the following problem I need to solve, but is strugling a bit. Would really appreciate it if someone can help.

In short in comes down to the following:

1. If the search key is in the array - it returns the smallest index i for which a[i] is equal to the key
2. If the search key is not in the array but greater - it returns the smallest index i as -i where a[i] is greater than the key
3. If the search key is not in the array but smaller - it returns -j where j is the index of the last element in the array

I have the code of searching for the key, but I'm not sure how to return the indexes as mentioned above...

```
import java.util.Arrays; 
public class BinarySearchIndex2 {

    // a working recursive version
    public static int search(String key, String[] a) {
        return search(key, a, 0, a.length);
    }

    public static int search(String key, String[] a, int lo, int hi) {
        // possible key indices in [lo, hi)
        if (hi <= lo) return -1;

        int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        int cmp = a[mid].compareTo(key);
        if      (cmp > 0) return search(key, a, lo, mid);
        else if (cmp < 0) return search(key, a, mid+1, hi);
        else              return mid;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String key = args[0];
        int sizeoflist = StdIn.readInt();
        String[] a = new String[sizeoflist];
            int counter = 0; //counter for while loop to fill array a

        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()){

            a[counter] = StdIn.readString();
            counter++;

        }

        Arrays.sort(a); // sort the words (if needed)

        if ( search(key, a) < 0) ; /* System.out.println();*/
        else if ( search(key, a) > 0 ) ;
        else if ( search(key, a) = 0 ) ;

    }
}
```

Would be really glad if someone can help me with this matter...

Thanks!

Comment: b.t.w - is this a homework assignment? (If so, please tag it accordingly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.compareTo` performs a lexicographical comparison. This means that it can decide that **"50">"100"**, whereas clearly 50<100 is what you would expect. This will affect your `Arrays.sort` call so your Array is already messed up.

Is it a must to have `public static int search(String key, String[] a)` as your API?

If you can change it to be `public static int search(int key, int[] a)` it will make your API work (assuming you don't have any bugs I missed).

Hope this was what you were referring to.

**Edit:** some fine tuning to the problem analysis.

Comment: @RonK Hi, yep, I tried that one, but I wasn't sure what the Int equivalent of compareTo is... Is it possible you can show me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: @ISJ: The equivalent of `compareTo` for `int`s is... normal `<`, `>=`, etc.

Comment: @ISJ - If you use `int` instead of `String` it should make the basic assumption of your API to be correct (that the Array is sorted and that comparison works correctly).

Comment: @ISJ - I think that the end of the `main` should be:
int index = search(key, a);
System.out.println("Index = " + index);
System.out.println("Value = " + a[index]);

Something like that (if I fully understood the requirement)

Comment: @ISJ: One last comment - i missed the question about `compareTo` for `int`.
Replace the line `int cmp = a[mid].compareTo(key);` with `int cmp = a[mid] - key;` it will do the trick.

Comment: @RonK Thanks, I really appreciate your help. I'll do as you told and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

The important point is here:

```
    if (hi <= lo) return -1;
```

This occurs when you got an sub-array to search of size zero, which means that the element is not there. Now think: what does the specification say about the return value here?

Comment: @Ebermann Ok, so if it is not there it should test for greater than or smaller than and then return the respective index??

Comment: Your conditions for the result are a bit strange, but I think one of `return -hi`, `return `-hi-1` and `return -hi + 1` does what you want. (Make some tests on paper, and get clear what you really want here.) There might be a special case for `hi == a.length`.